# how to check php nested array conditions

Tags: php

i am using jquery query builder , $rule is array
how to loop thround all inner arrays with their proper condition and returns the $rule is true or false?

```
$rule = array (
    'condition' => 'AND',
    'rules' => array (
        0 => array (
            'id' => 'name',
            'field' => 'name',
            'type' => 'string',
            'input' => 'text',
            'operator' => 'equal',
            'value' => 'bibin',
        ),
        1 => array (
            'id' => 'category',
            'field' => 'category',
            'type' => 'integer',
            'input' => 'select',
            'operator' => 'not_equal',
            'value' => 1,
        ),
        2 => array (
            'condition' => 'OR',
            'rules' => array (
                0 => array (
                    'id' => 'name',
                    'field' => 'name',
                    'type' => 'string',
                    'input' => 'text',
                    'operator' => 'equal',
                    'value' => 'john',
                ),
                1 => array (
                    'id' => 'category',
                    'field' => 'category',
                    'type' => 'integer',
                    'input' => 'select',
                    'operator' => 'equal',
                    'value' => 2,
                ),
                2 => array (
                    'condition' => 'OR',
                    'rules' => array (
                        0 => array (
                            'id' => 'name',
                            'field' => 'name',
                            'type' => 'string',
                            'input' => 'text',
                            'operator' => 'equal',
                            'value' => 'tech',
                        ),
                        1 => array (
                            'id' => 'price',
                            'field' => 'price',
                            'type' => 'double',
                            'input' => 'number',
                            'operator' => 'greater_or_equal',
                            'value' => 500,
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                3 => array (
                    'condition' => 'AND',
                    'rules' => array (
                        0 => array (
                            'id' => 'name',
                            'field' => 'name',
                            'type' => 'string',
                            'input' => 'text',
                            'operator' => 'equal',
                            'value' => 'top',
                        ),
                        1 => array (
                            'id' => 'category',
                            'field' => 'category',
                            'type' => 'integer',
                            'input' => 'select',
                            'operator' => 'equal',
                            'value' => 5,
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
        3 => array (
            'condition' => 'AND',
            'rules' => array (
                 0 => array (
                     'id' => 'name',
                     'field' => 'name',
                     'type' => 'string',
                     'input' => 'text',
                     'operator' => 'equal',
                     'value' => 'vishnu',
                 ),
                 1 => array (
                     'id' => 'price',
                     'field' => 'price',
                     'type' => 'double',
                     'input' => 'number',
                     'operator' => 'less_or_equal',
                     'value' => 1000,
                 ),
             ),
         ),
     )
);
```

I have a nested array called $rule.
I want to check the array returns true or false
Is any idea to check this array returns true or false?
How to iterarte and check with inner arrays?

Comment: You can use foreach loop

Comment: _I want to check the array returns true or false_ Can you expand on this sentence please. Check what is true or false

Comment: $rule['condition'] = 'AND'; so $rule['rules'][0],$rule['rules'][1],$rule['rules'][2],$rule['rules'][3] must be true for $rule  is true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a logical operator applying to some rules.

You might need a function that uses that operator on the differents rules.

I assume you build it that way

```
/*
 * $operator being 'OR' / 'AND'
 * $rules being an array
 * returns true or false
 */
function ApplyCondition($operator, $rules)
{
    // some code
}
```

I suggest you to build a function that will loop through the rules and check if the $rules array has a `'condition'` key. Since your original array is a tree (you don't know how deep can be the nested arrays), you **must** use a recursive function to parse it.

```
/*
 * $rules being an array
 * At first call, you have no condition yet, hence its default value is null
 * returns true or false
 */
function ParseRules($rules, $condition = null)
{
    if (isset($rules['condition']) && isset($rules['rules']))
    {
        /* 
         * An array with some rules and a condition was found.
         * Let's do a recursive call that will return true or false
         */
        return (ParseRules($rules['rules'], $rules['condition']));
    }
    else
    {
        /* 
         * An array without a condition was found.
         * Let's apply the upper function that will return true or false
         * to the previous recursive call
         */
        return (ApplyCondition($condition, $rules));
    }
}

/*
 * $operator being 'OR' / 'AND'
 * $rules being an array
 * returns true or false
 */
function ApplyCondition($operator, $rules)
{
    foreach ($rules as $rule)
    {
        if (isset($rule['condition']) && isset($rule['rules']))
        {
            /* 
             * An array with some rules and a condition was found.
             * Let's do a recursive call that will return true or false
             */
            $SomeBooleanValueToHandle = ParseRules($rule['rules'], $rule['condition']);
        }
        else
        {
            // some code
        }
    }
    return ($SomeBooleanValueToHandle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

U can use foreach loop to access every nested array:

```
echo "<pre>";
foreach ($rule as $r) {
    var_dump($r);
}
```

If u want to access some property (key => value), u can do it with `$r['id'];` `$r['field'];` .. etc.